# IndexError: List Index Out of Range in Python 3 While Using For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a for loop in python. My Code:

```
tc = int(input())
for tc_ct in range(tc):
    s = input().split()
    n = len(s)
    edited_s = s.copy()
    for i in range(n):
        i_1 = i+1
        if i == 0 and s[0] == s[i_1]:
                edited_s.pop(i)
        elif i == n-1:
            if s[i] == s[i-1]:
                edited_s.pop(i)
        else:
            if s[i] == s[i-1] or s[i] == s[i+1]:
                edited_s.pop(i)
    print("".join(edited_s))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Execution failed.
IndexError : list index out of range

Stack Trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/146373551/user_code.py", line 8, in <module>
        if i == 0 and s[0] == s[i_1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

can someone please tell me what this means

Comment: do you know what your error means?

Comment: Replace 4th line with: `n = len(s)-1` it's failing because for the last step of the loop you call `s[n]` (last i:=`n-1`, then you add 1).

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? Do you need help explaining what the error means? If you don't, did you try to make your own attempt to diagnose the problem? What exactly confuses you about this?

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
for i in range(n):
```

to:

```
for i in range(n-1):
```

This is important as when you do `i_1 = i+1`, when it reaches the last item in the list, it can't get the last item + 1 as there is no such thing. That is why it throws the exception.